# Read in and Merge or Concat Multiple files together into one dataframe on common ID column

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I am trying to concatenate multiple files in a directory. I am able to concatenate the files, however I am getting duplicated rows and columns. If a field doesn't exist in the input file, the output file should ideally show NaN or null.

Ideally the output would look as follows:

Merged.csv

```
   ItemID  Price  Discount ItemName          Desc  Barcode
0       1      4       2.0      Toy      For kids   667865
1       2     10       1.0     Game    For adults   998364
2       3      8       NaN      NaN  For everyone    43831
```

file1.csv

```
   ItemID  Price  Discount
0       1      4       2.0
1       2     10       1.0
2       3      8       NaN
```

file2.csv

```
   ItemID ItemName          Desc
0       1      Toy      For kids
1       2     Game    For adults
2       3      NaN  For everyone
```

file3.CSV

```
   ItemID  Barcode
0       1   667865
1       2   998364
2       3    43831
```

The following is the code I am working on:

```
import glob , os
import pandas as pd

path = '/location/test/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';').assign(file=os.path.basename(f)) for f in all_files]).to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

Comment: Instead of concat use pd.merge and pass on = ItemID in arguments.

Comment: IIUC, you need a merge or join `try pd.merge(left,right,on='ItemID')`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas Merging 101](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53645882/pandas-merging-101)

Comment: @r_hudson would that line of code be as follows

```
pd.merge(how = "right", on='ITEM_ID'[pd.read_csv(f, sep=';').assign(file=os.path.basename(f)) for f in all_files]).to_csv('merged.csv', index=False)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You can pass `axis=1` to `pd.concat` and use `.set_index('ItemID')` in order to `concat` on `ItemID`. You will just need to `reset_index()` at the end.
2. You can us `reduce` from `functools` with `merge`:

I prefer the former as it's a little bit cleaner, but I'm including the `reduce` solution in case it is more performant, or if you want to use some of the additional features unique to `.merge`:

Setup:

```
import glob , os
import pandas as pd
from functools import reduce

path = '/location/test/'
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*.csv"))
```

Method 1* (please see a note on this method at the end of the answer):

```
(pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';').set_index('ItemID') for f in all_files], axis=1)
 .reset_index().to_csv('merged.csv', index=False))
```

Method 2:

```
(reduce(lambda  left,right: pd.merge(left,right,on=['ItemID'], how='left'),
    [pd.read_csv(f, sep=';') for f in all_files]).to_csv('merged.csv', index=False))
```

The output in your .csv file will look like this:

```
Out[1]:

   ItemID  Price  Discount ItemName          Desc  Barcode
0       1      4       2.0      Toy      For kids   667865
1       2     10       1.0     Game    For adults   998364
2       3      8       NaN      NaN  For everyone    43831
```

For Method #1, this is not a universal solution, just because the same column that you are using to join the data exists in all dataframes. For example, if you have a base file with non-unique values, which you are trying to join other data to that have unique values, then the other files will join together, but the base file will not join to the others and you willl receive a `ValueError`. Below, first I read in the base file. Then I `concat` all other files except the base file. Then, I join the base file and other files together with `join`, but pd.concat, won't work if there are non-unique values in the key, so it's better to use `join` or `merge`:

```
import pandas as pd
import glob , os

path = 'Downloads\\'
base_file = os.path.join(path, "EVS1CPP.csv")
all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "*1CPP.csv"))
all_files.remove(base_file)
df_base = pd.read_csv(base_file, sep=';').set_index('ARTICLE_ID')
dfs = pd.concat([pd.read_csv(f, sep=';').set_index('ARTICLE_ID') for f in all_files], axis=1)
df = df_base.join(dfs, how='outer').rename_axis('ARTICLE_ID').reset_index()
df
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanations with each method!